# Split a string on whitespace, numbers, and operators with regex

Tags: java, regex

I was wondering if it was possible to split a string on whitespace, and avoid all numbers, whitespace and operators such as + and -

This is what I have, but I believe it is incorrect

```
  String [] temp = expression.split("[ \\+ -][0-9] ");
```

Suppose I have an expression

```
x+y+3+5+z
```

I want to get rid of everything else and only put x, y, and z into the array

Comment: *split a string on whitespace, and avoid all ... whitespace*? Can you give a few examples of what you want to happen on a variety of inputs and what the output should be?

Comment: What I mean is, that whitespace should not be in the array that I split

Comment: +1 for providing the example. That makes your question about 920 times more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean this:

```
String[] temp = expression.split("[\\s0-9+-]+");
```

This splits on whitespace, 0 to 9, `+` and `-`. Note that the characters appear in a single character class, not multiple separate character classes. Also the `-` doesn't need escaping here because it is at the end of the character class.

Comment: your solution is good, but it gives extra blank spots in the array. Try it with 2 + y. It gives an array size of 3 but only y is in there. The other two are empty.

Comment: @Steffan Harris: That's how split works. Read the documentation: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29 *Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.* Notice that it doesn't say that *leading* empty strings are removed. You'll probably have to remove them yourself, or alternatively don't use split, use a `Matcher` instead and write a regular expression for what you want to keep instead of what you want to discard.

Comment: yes, my solution has the same "problem" - a leading "separator" is treated as if there's any empty token in front of it.

Comment: Or you could do a `expression.replaceAll(" ","").split("[\\s0-9+-]+");`  No whitespace, no problem.

Comment: That doesn't work on Unicode, which just happens to be Java’s native character set.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're after:

```
String[] tmp = expression.split("[^a-zA-Z]+");
```

which should treat the separator as being *anything* that isn't a sequence of letters.

**Test Run**

```
public class foo {
    static public void main(String[] args) {
        String[] res = args[0].split("[^a-zA-Z]+");
        for (String r: res) {
            System.out.println(r);
        }
    }
}

% javac foo.java
% java foo x+y+3+5+z
x
y
z
```